# How to read custom log file using filebeat and read and create a visualisation of data using kibana

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat, elk, kibana-7

I have stocks.log as follows , I want to read and draw the graph(kibana visualisation ) for each of the stock

```
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Stock = TCS.NS,  Date = 2002-08-12
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Volume=212976
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Low=38.724998474121094
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | High=40.0
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Open=38.724998474121094
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Close=39.70000076293945
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Stock = TCS.NS,  Date = 2002-08-13
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Volume=153576
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Low=38.875
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | High=40.38750076293945
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Open=39.75
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Close=39.162498474121094
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Stock = TCS.NS,  Date = 2002-08-14
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Volume=822776
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Low=35.724998474121094
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | High=39.25
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Open=39.25
2021/06/13 17:58:42 :     INFO | Close=36.462501525878906
```

Is it possible to use filebeat-> Elastic-> Kibana for this use case.
I am able to read the message per stock per date as message in elastic.
But not able to parse the data and visualise in kibana.

I used the following in ingest pipeline, able to see the fields extracted properly now

```
[
  {
    "grok": {
      "field": "message",
      "patterns": [
        "%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Stock = %{GREEDYDATA:Stock}\n%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Date = %{GREEDYDATA:Bdate}\n%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Volume=%{NUMBER:Volume}\n%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Low=%{BASE10NUM:Low}\n%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}High=%{BASE10NUM:High}\n%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Open=%{BASE10NUM:Open}\n%{GREEDYDATA:irrelevant_data}Close=%{BASE10NUM:Close}"
      ]
    }
  }
```

The problem is now, Date is coming as string field, not sure how to convert that one to proper date format.

Comment: Thanks Bar Azoulay , right now managed to read multiline into a single message, For reading the message into proper index, i am trying use grok, for which tutorials so far is not easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

There are some filebeat processors you can read about it here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filtering-and-enhancing-data.html

But in general, parsing logs is not part of filebeat scope, I recommend using logstash for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was thought it could be done using `Aggregate`, but then I realize your logs have no IDs. So I think this is a very good sample for filebeat's module [Multiline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html)
Using the Application events, If I'm right the beginning of your logs should be      `INFO | Stock =` and the end should be      `INFO | Close=`. They have a very perfect one for this case. This seems to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I would suggest you send the data to Logstash from filebeat, as the former has various filters to manipulate your data for which it'll be easier for you to create visualizations on top of it.

So, your output section would look like this:

```
      hosts: ["LOGSTASH_IP:PORT"]
      index: stocks-monitor
```